# Can't run cfgmaker

Tags: centos, monitoring, mrtg

I need to create a config file for `mrtg` using cfgmaker, but no metter what I try I always get the following:

cfgmaker --global 'WorkDir: /var/www/mrtg' --output=/etc/mrtg/mrtg.cfg

```
Usage:
    cfgmaker [options] [community@]router [[options] [community@]router ...]

Options:
     --ifref=nr    interface references by Interface Number (default)
     --ifref=ip                     ... by Ip Address
     --ifref=eth                        ... by Ethernet Number
     --ifref=descr                      ... by Interface Description
     --ifref=name                       ... by Interface Name
     --ifref=type                       ... by Interface Type

     --ifdesc=nr       interface description uses Interface Number (default)
     --ifdesc=ip                        ... uses Ip Address
     --ifdesc=eth                       ... uses Ethernet Number
     --ifdesc=descr                     ... uses Interface Description
     --ifdesc=name                      ... uses Interface Name
     --ifdesc=catname                   ... uses CatOS Interface Name
     --ifdesc=ppname                    ... uses Passport Port Name
     --ifdesc=alias                     ... uses Interface Alias
     --ifdesc=type                      ... uses Interface Type

     --if-filter=f     Test every interface against filter f to decide wether
                       or not to include that interface into the collection.
                       Currently f is being evaluated as a Perl expression
                       and it's truth value is used to reject or accept the
                       interface.
                       (Experimental, under development, might change)

     --if-template=templatefile
                       Replace the normal target entries for the interfaces
                       with an entry as specified by the contents in the file
                       templatefile.  The file is supposed to contain Perl
                       code to be executed to generate the lines for the
                       target in the configuration file.
                       (Experimental, under development, might change)

     --host-template=templatefile
                       In addition to creating targets for a host's interfaces
                       do also create targets for the host itself as specified
                       by the contents in the file templatefile.  The file is
                       supposed to contain Perl code to be executed to generate
                       the lines for the host related targets (such as CPU,
                       ping response time measurements etc.) in the config-
                       uration file.
                       (Experimental, under development, might change)

     --global "x: a"   add global config entries

     --no-down         do not look at admin or opr status of interfaces

     --show-op-down    show interfaces which are operatively down

     --zero-speed=spd  use this speed in bits-per-second as the interface
                       speed for all interfaces that return a speed of 0
                       via ifSpeed/ifHighSpeed.  100Mbps = 100000000

     --subdirs=format  give each router its own subdirectory, naming each per
                       "format", in which HOSTNAME and SNMPNAME will be
                       replaced by the values of those items -- for instance,
                       --subdirs=HOSTNAME or --subdirs="HOSTNAME (SNMPNAME)"

     --noreversedns    do not reverse lookup ip numbers

     --community=cmty  Set the default community string to "cmty" instead of
                       "public".

     --enable-ipv6     Enable IPv6 support, if the required libraries are
                       present. Numeric IPv6 addresses must be enclosed
                       in square brackets, e.g. public@[2001:760:4::1]:161

     --use-16bit       Use 16bit SNMP request IDs to query all routers.

     --snmp-options=:[<port>][:[<tmout>][:[<retr>][:[<backoff>][:<ver>]]]]

                       Specify default SNMP options to be appended to all
                       routers following.  Individual fields can be empty.
                       Routers following might override some or all of the
               options given to --snmp-options.

     --dns-domain=domain
               Specifies a domain to append to the name of all
               routers following.

     --nointerfaces    Don't do generate any configuration lines for interfaces,
                       skip the step of gathering interface information and
                       don't run any interface template code.

     --interfaces      Generate configuration lines for interfaces (this is the
                       default).  The main purpose of this option is to negate
                       an --nointerfaces appearing earlier on the command line.

     --help            brief help message
     --man             full documentation
     --version         print the version of cfgmaker

     --output=file     output filename default is STDOUT
```

Answer (score 1):

The usage statement clearly says that `cfgmaker` requires a `router` argument, but you haven't provided one.

Add in your router argument and optional SNMP community:

```
cfgmaker --global 'WorkDir: /var/www/mrtg' --output=/etc/mrtg/mrtg.cfg public@192.0.2.1
```